# Formik onBlur and ErrorMessage do not work together

Tags: javascript, formik

In the following code, the ErrorMessage only works if I comment out the onBlur.

I've tried multiple fixes, but none work.  Any help is appreciated!

```
                  <Field
                    id='name'
                    name='name'
                    placeholder='building'
                    onBlur={isValid ? handleBlur : null}
                    className={`form-control ${
                      touched.name && errors.name ? 'text-danger' : ''
                    }`}
                  />

                  <ErrorMessage
                    name='name'
                    component='div'
                    className='text-d
                  />
```

I tried everything and nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formik's default `onBlur` handler takes care of "touching" the associated field:

```js
      setFieldTouched(field, true);
```

`ErrorMessage` only renders if [the associated field has been marked as touched](https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage) so you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks,  I wrote it like this:           onBlur={(e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                          if (isValid) {
                            handleBlur(e);
                            setFieldTouched('name', true);
                          }
                        }}

Comment: You will need to mark the field as touched even if it is _not_ valid. Recall that the `ErrorMessage` will only show if the field is touched and not valid!

Comment: thanks.     onBlur={(e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                          if (isValid) {
                            handleBlur(e);
                          }
                          setFieldTouched('name', true);
                        }}